# Is there a pythonic way of counting the occurrences of each element in an array?

Tags: python, arrays

Just like the title suggests, I just wanted to know whether there is a pythonic way of counting the occurrence of each element in an array. I have implemented the code below:

```py
my_array = ['dog', 'cat', 'rabbit', 'rabbit', 'elephant', 'bee', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'elephant']

occurrences = {}
for item in my_array:
    try:
        occurrences[item] += 1
    except KeyError:
        occurrences[item] = 1
```

And it gives me the ff result:

```
dog: 2
cat: 3
rabbit: 2
elephant: 2
bee: 1
```

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

PS: Sorry if this question is kind of stupid. I might delete this if someone agrees.

PPS: If this question is duplicated, can u drop the link and I'll give it a go. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-do-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Comment: There is the `Counter` class from collections.

Comment: @Joooeey not really. it only counts a given item in a list. My problem is more like counting the occurrence of each element and I have solved it. Just wondering if there's a pythonic way of doing so.

Comment: @Hansel, the second answer to the linked question answers your question pythonically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5829377/4691830

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Counter` from the `collections` module in the standard library is what you are looking for.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Used like so:

```py
from collections import Counter

my_array = ['dog', 'cat', 'rabbit', 'rabbit', 'elephant', 'bee', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'elephant']
c = Counter(my_array)
```

`C` then returns
`Counter({'cat': 3, 'dog': 2, 'rabbit': 2, 'elephant': 2, 'bee': 1})`

You can also convert this to a dictionary of elements: counts.
`dict(c)`